# How many $n$ digit numbers can be written using only certain digits?

Tags: permutations

For example, how would I calculate how many $5$ digit numbers I can write using only digits $0, 2, 2, 3, 3$?

Is $4\times5\times5\times5\times5$ correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Does for example 02233 count as a 5 digit number? Or is that a four digit number?

Comment: So each number you create has to use 2 2's, 2 3's, and 1 0?

Comment: Nope, I don't think 02233 is a number.

Comment: What about 33333?  I assume no, but it would be less clear if those  digits were all different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Total non similar combinations possible=$\dfrac{5!}{2!\cdot 2!}=30$

Number of combinations where digit "$0$" is at start(assuming $02233$ isn't a 5-digit number for instance)=$\dfrac{4!}{2!\cdot 2!}=6$

Number of valid 5-digit numbers=$30-6=24$

Note: If "$0$" is allowed at the start of a number, the answer is $30$.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Since 0 isn't allowed as a leading digit, you have 4 choices for where to put it, and then you have $\binom{4}{2}=6$ choices for where to place the 2's;

so there are $4\cdot6=24$ possible 5-digit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `4×5×5×5×5` is the wrong answer is because it will have duplicates in it. How?
Here's how

Let's assume we take `2 0 2 3 3` as first number, now if I change the first and second `2` I still get the same number, i.e. `2 0 2 3 3`. Hence with your answer, you are considering all these numbers as the different ones. To get the correct answer, `K Rmth`'s answer is good enough.